# Can v-if trigger something? Does v-if raise an event?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to catch an event and do something when v-if toggles. A conditionally rendered element is rendering. It should be possible to get notified of this, no?

Comment: Terrible question! Was I ever this naive? Vue stuff should not watch (or listen to) other vue stuff.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can setup a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the property that is responsible for the truthy-ness for the conditional rendering (`v-if`).

**html**

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-if="toggleElement">MY ELEMENT</div>
    <button @click="toggleElement = !toggleElement">TOGGLE</button>
</div>
```

**script**

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
    data: {
        toggleElement: false
    },
    watch: {
        toggleElement(newValue){
            //do something if toggleElement changes
            alert("Element's v-if toggled");
        }
    }
})
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/ap86gnc2/1/)

Comment: Correct answer. and if the condition in `v-if` is not a simple property but a more complex expression, put that in a computed property instead of the template, and observe the computed property.

Answer (score 3):

It would trigger `mounted` if it would be applied to the component.

So if in your parent you would have:

```
<template>
<div>
<child v-if='test'/>
</div>
</template>
```

When test is changed, you would trigger `mounted` of child.

Comment: Yes, and that would guarantee that the dom is fully rendered

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact topic with a popup that needs to be filled first (via v-if) and then animated with GSAP.

The binding is bonded with the clearance of a function

```
 <section class="PopupBlok" v-if="$store.state.popup && animateOpen()">
```

But since the function needs to "give its ok" by returning true, you can't directly animate in the `animateOpen()` function. To fix this, you postpone your animation for one tick like so:

```
 animateOpen() {
  this.$nextTick(() => { <Do Animation here> })
  return true
```

}

Therefore your function gives it's OK, and in the next loop all elements are available for animation.

I assume it would work with `setTimeout` as well, but `$nextTick` is the vue-way